# Get a List of Available Drupal Views

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I'd like to set up a configuration page for my Drupal module that contains a dropdown where the user selects one of the available views.  Is there an easy way to obtain a list of all available views on the system?  All I need is an array of all the views' names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [views_all_get_views function](http://api.zzolo.org/api/function/views_get_all_views/drupal-6) ... this returns an array of views, indexed by name, so you could wrap array_keys() around the result to get the names.